# Unable to create Hbase table using Hive query through Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-spark-sql

Using the following tutorial: https://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-integration-with-hive/, I was able to do the HBase integration with Hive. After the configuration I was successfully able to create Hbase table using Hive query with Hive table mapping.

Hive query:

```
CREATE TABLE upc_hbt(key string, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,value:value")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "upc_hbt");
```

Spark-Scala:

```
val createTableHql : String = s"CREATE TABLE upc_hbt2(key string, value string)"+
      "STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'"+
      "WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,value:value')"+
      "TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = 'upc_hbt2')"

    hc.sql(createTableHql)
```

But when I execute the same Hive query through Spark it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler
```

It’s seem like during the Hive execution through Spark it can’t find the auxpath jar location. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.